# What's meant here by "anything so odd as a religious man"?

Tags: phrase-meaning

In "The Vampire of the Village" by G. K. Chesterton, Father Brown was talking about a fake parson who was a stage actor, saying:

> ‘All this time there was a subconscious notion running in my head; something I couldn’t fix in my memory; and then it came to me suddenly. This is a Stage Parson. That is exactly the vague venerable old fool who would be the nearest notion a popular playwright or play-actor of the old school had of **anything so odd
> as a religious man**.

What's meant here by "anything so odd as a religious man"?

Are the religious men odd?

Answer (score 1):

Father Brown, a religious man, is thinking of the viewpoint of a playwright or actor, and he thinks that such a person would believe that a religious man is an odd thing. Hence, the playwright or actor would cast or portray him as a vague, venerable old fool: "a Stage Parson".

Comment: @AhmedSamir You are welcome. I just searched for the phrase "anything so odd as" at google, and I found that there are many examples of it, so you can get a better idea of its sense.